# Windows 8.1 - Can't run programs as administrator

Tags: windows-8.1

strange problem I've never encountered before. If I right click a program and choose "run as administrator" then just nothing happens. No message box, no program, just nothing.

I've tested it with something easy as cmd:

- Run it normally -> Ok.
- Right click - Run as administrator -> Nothing happens
- Creating shortcut with option to run it as administrator -> UAC pops up and I can run it as admin.

Any idea why right click - run as administrator is not working anymore?

**System:**

- Windows 8.1 Pro N (64 bit)
- Intel i5
- 16GB RAM

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [start Windows in safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode) or [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: @and31415: Haven't tried it yet. I will give it a try and report then.

Comment: @and31415: Starting Windows in safe mode doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you tweak the UAC settings? Try creating a new user account and check whether it works any different there.